# Picker with SegmentPickerStyle() doesn’t show picker title in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, title, picker, segment

I created  a segment  picker for select gender in that segment picker I have to option one for Male and another for Female. Picker is working fine But set title on  with picker it’s not showing. I set title **Select Gender** which is not showing as a title on the Picker.

```
struct ManagerChildrenView: View {

        //MARK: Properties
        @State var selectedGender = 0
        let genders = ["Male", "Female"]

        var body: some View {

            Form{
                Section{
                    Picker("Select Gender", selection: $selectedGender) {

                        ForEach(0..<genders.count) { index in
                            Text(self.genders[index]).tag(index).font(.title)
                        }
                    }.pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: It seems `SegmentedPickerStyle` does not show the title. You need to create a custom title for it.

Answer (score 6):

Label is not used for `SegmentedPickerStyle`. Instead you can use the following approach

[image]

```
HStack {
    Text("Select Gender")
    Picker("", selection: $selectedGender) {

        ForEach(0..<genders.count) { index in
            Text(self.genders[index]).tag(index).font(.title)
        }
    }.pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
}
```

Comment: thanks, but what's the mean of title in the picker with SegmentedPickerStyle() . Why i add new View in the form of text on Screen.

Comment: @Ravindra_Bhati, that is a question to Apple )) Probably such their vision of segmented picker. You can always submit feedback to Apple.

Comment: The label / String that you pass in the `Picker` is also used by screen readers to read it @Ravindra_Bhati