# SwiftUI how come using a segmented picker style removes the text?

Tags: swift, swiftui

```
Section
      {
          Picker("Tip percentage", selection: $smth)
          {
               ForEach(tipPercentages, id: .self)
                 {
                      Text($0, format: .percent)
                 }
         }
         .pickerStyle(.segmented)
    }
```

So I have this line of code and I just have a tiny question, before I use the pickerStyle modifier on the Picker View the text always shows up and gets displayed. But then when I use this .segmented modifier suddenly the "Tip percentage" text just disappears..? Why exactly is this happening? If this is happening what is even the point of having it be there??

Comment: I think that's how that style is designed.

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/60274643/12299030?

Answer (score 0):

The label is not shown on segmented pickers. However, the label is read by screen readers. It’s a good practice to put a label on them for accessibility.

If you really need to show that text, use a `Text` view. (In a HStack or something)